# How do I cofigure the volume mounts for a Postgres Kubernetes container (OSX & Minikube)

Tags: postgresql, macos, kubernetes, minikube

I am trying to setup a postgres pod using minikube. I have the following in my pod config in my deployment

```
volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
              name: postgredb
volumes:
    - name: postgredb
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: postgres-pv-claim
```

but when I run I get

```
initdb: error: directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data" exists but is not empty
It contains a dot-prefixed/invisible file, perhaps due to it being a mount point.
Using a mount point directly as the data directory is not recommended.
Create a subdirectory under the mount point.
```

so I change to

```
volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
          name: postgredb
          subPath: db
```

But then I get...

```
2021-02-19 03:53:24.760 UTC [30] LOG:  could not link file "pg_wal/xlogtemp.30" to "pg_wal/000000010000000000000001": Operation not permitted
2021-02-19 03:53:24.761 UTC [30] FATAL:  could not open file "pg_wal/000000010000000000000001": No such file or directory
```

This is on OSX using minikube, how do I get it to work?

I also tried

```
      env:
        - name: PGDATA
          value: /var/lib/postgresql/data/db_data
      envFrom:
        - configMapRef:
            name: db-config
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
          name: postgredb
          subPath: db_data
```

But still get

```
2021-02-19 03:53:24.760 UTC [30] LOG:  could not link file "pg_wal/xlogtemp.30" to "pg_wal/000000010000000000000001": Operation not permitted
2021-02-19 03:53:24.761 UTC [30] FATAL:  could not open file "pg_wal/000000010000000000000001": No such file or directory
```

Comment: Does this issue help: https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/792 ?

Comment: @NizarM thanks for the idea, I don't think it does there is one person at the end that mentions a similar issue but no resultion